# Qt Charts Bar Plot Resize Crash

Tags: c++, qt, plot, bar-chart, qtcharts

### Situation:

I wrote a bar plot using `QtCharts`, `QChartView`, `QChart`, `QBarSeries`, `QBarSet`, `QValueAxis` and `QCategoryAxis` and it works fine.

### Problem:

When i resize the window or use `QRubberband`on the plot, it crashes.

### What i tried:

Every other plot i wrote is not affected by that problem, including the ones using `QStackedBarSeries`. The Problem also occured in another program i wrote in the same situation.

### Code - Head:

```
int D_Plot::Plot_Stat_Multi_MeanMedian(
QChartView *pChartView, 
vector<vector<double> > *vv_SetSta, 
bool pl_mean, 
bool pl_sd, 
bool pl_median, 
bool pl_adm, 
QString name_title, 
QString name_categories, 
QString name_y)
```

### Code - Body:

```
//Chart
QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->setTitle(name_title);

//Sets
QBarSet set_mean("Mean");
QBarSet set_sdev("Standard Deviation");
QBarSet set_medi("Median");
QBarSet set_aadm("Average Absolute Deviation from Median");

//Categories
QStringList categories;

//Series
QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();
for(unsigned int set = 0; set < vv_SetSta->size(); set++)
{
    if(pl_mean)     set_mean.append((*vv_SetSta)[set][c_STAT_MEAN_ARITMETIC]);
    if(pl_sd)       set_sdev.append((*vv_SetSta)[set][c_STAT_STAN_DEV_SAMPLE]);
    if(pl_median)   set_medi.append((*vv_SetSta)[set][c_STAT_MEDIAN]);
    if(pl_adm)      set_aadm.append((*vv_SetSta)[set][c_STAT_ABS_DEV_MED]);

    categories.append(QString::number(set));
}
if(pl_mean)     series->append(&set_mean);
if(pl_sd)       series->append(&set_sdev);
if(pl_median)   series->append(&set_medi);
if(pl_adm)      series->append(&set_aadm);
chart->addSeries(series);

//Axis
QBarCategoryAxis *X_axis = new QBarCategoryAxis();
X_axis->append(categories);
X_axis->setTitleText(name_categories);
chart->setAxisX(X_axis, series);

QValueAxis *Y_axis = new QValueAxis();
Y_axis->setTitleText(name_y);
chart->setAxisY(Y_axis, series);


//Showing
pChartView->setChart(chart);

return ER_Okay;
```

Comment: Please provide at least a stack trace of the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your QBarSet objects locally (i.e. not via the new operator) and passing a pointer to these sets to the QBarSet::append method which AFAIK takes ownership if the objects pointed to i.e feels obliged to de-allocate them when going out of scope. This is bound to fail with locally allocated objects.

Comment: That indeed was the problem. Thanks.